# php alternative to explode

Tags: php, html, apache, http

```
<?php
$URI_parts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $URI_parts[0];
?>
```

I've read that explode was rather heavy on resources, and I was curious if there's an optimal alternative that will perform the same task in this case.

The code above is destroying everything following a query string `?` including parameters. I need to find the least costly method to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [**parse_url**()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), like this :

```php
$URI_parts = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $URI_parts['path'];
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` generally isn't a full URL though, it's just the part after the protocol, host and port (the OP shouldn't use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for removing the query parameters).

Comment: @alex: That's fine, parse_url() handles such partial URLs too.

Comment: Can you provide an example in the format of the code in my OP? I'm reading the php.net document but am not completely sure of how to use it, because of inclusion of print_r and such.

Comment: @questy: I added a code example to the answer above. I hope you don't mind, Christopher.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?", TRUE)`. Alternatively, you could use `strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?")`.

It should stop matching after it's satisfied.

As an aside, you shouldn't not use a PHP function because you heard [citation needed] that it was slow. You should use the appropriate tool for the job, and if that's too slow after finding a performance issue, measuring it and determining it's your use of that function, then consider refactoring.

Comment: +1 for "use the appropriate tool for the job". (In this case, though, I think Christopher Morrissey's answer actually gives the appropriate tool for this job.)